# How to keep the arrow position unchanged when restart it using requestAnimationFrame()?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I tried to understand an [example](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/asynchronous/loops-and-intervals/start-and-stop-spinner.html) on MDN.

The effect of the [current code](https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/javascript/asynchronous/loops-and-intervals/start-and-stop-spinner.html) is a bit confusing to me - after a pause if you wait a while and start again, the position of the arrow is not where it originally stopped.

How to make sure to restart where I left off? I thought of a way as below, but I am not very satisfied with it.

```js
const spinner = document.querySelector('div')
let rotateCount = 0
let startTime = null
let rAF
let spinning = false
let previousRotateCount = 0
let hasStopped = false
let rotateInterval

function draw(timestamp) {
  if (hasStopped) {
    // The angle of each rotation is constant
    rotateCount += rotateInterval
    rotateCount %= 360
  } else {
    if (!startTime) {
      startTime = timestamp
    }
    rotateCount = (timestamp - startTime) / 3
    rotateCount %= 360
    rotateInterval = rotateCount - previousRotateCount
    previousRotateCount = rotateCount
  }
  console.log(rotateCount)
  spinner.style.transform = `rotate(${rotateCount}deg)`

  rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (spinning) {
    hasStopped = true
    cancelAnimationFrame(rAF)
  } else {
    draw()
  }
  spinning = !spinning
})
```

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div>↻</div>
```

I hope there is a better way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example code is a bit weird, they define a global `rotateCount` that's never actually used and their use of the timestamp is ... yes, confusing.

Their `let rotateCount = (timestamp - startTime) / 3;` makes it that the animation will take 1080ms to perform a full revolution (360deg x 3 = 1080ms).

But this is based on the difference between the current time and the start time. So indeed, even if you pause the animation, when restarting it will just like it never did pause.

To make this, you'd need to actually use the global `rotateCount` (by not redefining a new variable inside `draw`), and increment it every time by the amount of rotation that was needed since last draw, and not since the overall beginning.

Then you just need to ensure that the last-drawn timestamp gets updated when you resume the animation and you get your animation to actually pause and resume.

```js
const spinner = document.querySelector('div');

const duration = 1080; // ms to perform a full revolution
const speed = 360 / duration;

let rotateCount = 0;
let rAF;

// we'll set this in the starting code
// (in the click event listener)
let lastTime;

let spinning = false;

// Create a draw() function
function draw(timestamp) {
  // get the elapsed time since the last time we did fire
  // we directly get the remainder from "duration"
  // because we're in a looping animation
  const elapsed = (timestamp - lastTime) % duration;
  // for next time, lastTime is now
  lastTime = timestamp;
  // add to the previous rotation how much we did rotate
  rotateCount += elapsed * speed;
  
  // Set the rotation of the div to be equal to rotateCount degrees
  spinner.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotateCount + 'deg)';

  // Call the next frame in the animation
  rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// event listener to start and stop spinner when page is clicked

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(spinning) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);
    spinning = false;
  } else {
    // reset lastTime with either the current frame time
    // or JS time if unavailable
    // so that in the next draw
    // we see only the time that did elapse
    // from now to then
    lastTime = document.timeline?.currentTime || performance.now();
    // schedule the next draw
    requestAnimationFrame( draw )
    spinning = true;
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10rem;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>↻</div>
```